# Can't Use Installed fonts in gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome, fonts

Just got a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04. Can't use Powerline/Nerd Fonts in gnome-terminal. They don't show up in the list of fonts.(However the fonts are installed, and they show up in the menus for Firefox and Tilix).

I've refreshed the font cache, and also tried to change the permissions of the font(chmod-ing it). No use. Used to work just fine on 17.10. This broke after upgrading to 18.04

Comment: As suggested elsewhere in the forum, please explain exactly what you did, step by step, in lieu of "Already tried.... the rest of the solutions..."

Answer (score 3):

One way to get Gnome Terminal to use a different font is to change the system wide monospace font. You can do this with the Gnome Tweak Tool, install by executing `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool` in terminal.

See screenshot:
[FiraCode selected in Gnome Tweak Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00wsv.png)